# Angularjs - set a scope (variable) on scope $http - POST

Tags: angularjs, http, variables, post, scope

I'm reaching out to the community as I'm getting stuck with Angularjs... Apologize as I'm quite new to Angularjs.

With the code below, at the line:

```
$scope.momentum = [{mmnt_desc:"bouhhhh"},{mmnt_desc:"beeuuhh"}];
```

from:

```
$scope.showMomentDay=function(date){
$http.post('back/event_availability.php', {"date": date})
    .success(function(data){
    $scope.momentum = [{mmnt_desc:"bouhhhh"},{mmnt_desc:"beeuuhh"}];
        //$scope.momentDay = data[0];
        console.log($scope.momentum);
    })
    .error(function (data){
        console.log("Erreur:" + data);
    })

};
```

When I put this piece of code outside the scope.showMomementDay(), my view displays it correctly,  no problem. However, when I set $scope.momentum **inside** the function, I definitely get the object sent to the console (array(object, object)) **but** I don't get anything being displayed.

Below this is the view:

```
<section class="st_panel">
   <div ng-app="app" >
     <div ng-controller="dateController">
        <div ng-repeat="mmt in momentum">{{mmt.mmnt_desc}}</div>
    </div> 
   </div>    
</section>
```

Could you please help me figure out what I've been missing there? 
Thanks,

Comment: Make sure that your call come to success. means, request process the response or any error? track it through your browser developer tool

Comment: show us your view and whole js part. If `$scope.momentum` is logged but you cant see it in view, then it seems like view does not have acces to that scope. Make plnkr if possible